Understanding "the positive carry paid for your option"
I'm reading Hedge Fund Market Wizards and there's an interview talking about how to trade when you know you're in the bubbled stock market.

Q: How then did you position yourself during 2006 and 2007?
A: We recognized that we would underperform the bulls by quite a bit because in a bubble the true believers will always win. That’s fine. You just need to make decent returns and wait until the market turns. Then you can make great returns. What I believe in is compounding and not losing money. We were quite happy to be part of the bubble, but to do it in positions that were highly liquid, so that we could exit the market quickly if we wanted to. One of the biggest mistakes people made was to join in the bubble, but to do it in positions for which there was no exit. All markets look liquid during the bubble, but it’s the liquidity after the bubble ends that matters. We did a lot of our trades through options—positions like buying calls in currencies with a carry because the positive carry paid for your option.

My questions,

The interviewee claims the stock options are more liquid than stock itself, so that he can exit the market quickly, but is that still true when the market crashes?
By because the positive carry paid for your option, how could the interest rate difference pay for the option? I don't see the connection between a carry trade and the option trade here, so I couldn't understand it.


I don't know how you can tell that you are in a stock market bubble, so the question may be moot. Trying to time the market does not work at a retail level, and is questionably successful for pros.

@keshlam The interview talks about the 2008 crisis, and how to identify a bubbled market is not the question. It's just the background information I filled in here.

My point is that it is quite possible that it doesn't make any sense. Being published has surprisingly little to do with being right. Or coherent.
